# Create a ranking variable with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data

```
df = data.frame(name=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), score = c(10, 10, 9, 8))
```

I want to add a new column with the ranking. This is what I'm doing:

```
df %>% mutate(ranking = rank(score, ties.method = 'first'))
#   name score ranking
# 1    A    10       3
# 2    B    10       4
# 3    C     9       2
# 4    D     8       1
```

However, my desired result is:

```
#   name score ranking
# 1    A    10       1
# 2    B    10       1
# 3    C     9       2
# 4    D     8       3
```

Clearly `rank` does not do what I have in mind. What function should I be using?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `dense_rank` from "dplyr" -- but applied in a reverse order than what `rank` normally does.

Try this:

```
df %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(score)))
#   name score rank
# 1    A    10    1
# 2    B    10    1
# 3    C     9    2
# 4    D     8    3
```

Comment: Prbly want to use `desc(score)` even though `-score` works. Hadley has poked me abt that a cpl times.

Comment: Is it possible to have the ranking of C be 3 and for D 4?

Comment: @Ignacio instead of using `dense_rank` use `min_rank`

Comment: aaah thank you. Only to say than `arrange (desc())` before`dense_rank()` doesn't work in that case for items outside the `group_by()`. It's what I've tried during times.

Answer (score 8):

Other solution when you need to apply the rank to all variables (not just one).

```
df = data.frame(name = c("A","B","C","D"),
                score=c(10,10,9,8), score2 = c(5,1,9,2))

select(df, -name) %>% mutate_all(funs(dense_rank(desc(.))))
```

Comment: `dplyr` has `desc()`, you don't need `inv_d`. (It's nice because it works for many data types, not just numeric.) You also don't need to do this in separate steps, you can go all at once: `mutate_all(df, funs(dense_rank(desc(.))))`

Comment: funs() is now deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.  What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

@user101089 --- you can try out with this alternative way:

```
df = data.frame(name = c("A","B","C","D"),
                score=c(10,10,9,8), score2 = c(5,1,9,2))

df %>% mutate(rank_score = dense_rank(desc(score)), 
                  rank_score2 = dense_rank(desc(score2)))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post an answer to this question but it is not clear to me how this answer is different to the existing answers. Please edit your post to make it clear how this is answer is different / an improvement.